# Passing a parameter into an anonymous Func

Tags: c#, parameter-passing, anonymous-function, func

The following code outputs `bee`:

```
    var str = "B";

    var env = new Func<string>(() => {
        switch (str)
        {
            case "A":
                return "aye";
            case "B":
                return "bee";
            default:
                return "see";
        }
    }).Invoke();

    Console.WriteLine(env);
```

How can I pass the str variable as a parameter to the anonymous function? The closest I can get is this:

```
    var str = "B";

    Func<string, string> env = a => {
        switch (a)
        {
            case "A":
                return "aye";
            case "B":
                return "bee";
            default:
                return "see";
        }
    };

    Console.WriteLine(env(str));
```

But that is not anonymous, as it is named `env`.

Is it possible to use the first form and still pass in a parameter?

Comment: "But that is not anonymous, as it is named env." - that is still an anonymous method; `env` is the name of a local variable that holds a delegate instance that *points* to the anonymous method. Can you perhaps be more specific as to what you're trying to achieve, and what you mean by "anonymous" here (as it doesn't seem to be quite the usual meaning)?

Comment: `var env = new Func<string, string>((a) => { ...}.Invoke(str)`?

Comment: Thank you @dmitry-bychenko - that should have been obvious! Please post that as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I think you are missing one `)` before `.Invoke` plus `(a)` can be just `a` :)

Comment: @marc-gravell You are right, of course - I was looking for a closure without a pointer - something which exists only for the time in which it is used. What name would you give my first code snippet?

Comment: that's *also* a delegate (reference) that points to an anonymous method instance - just... without a closure. (edit: see my later comment - I snafud the language here; the first version has a closure, the second version does not)

Comment: "I was looking for a closure without a pointer" - if you want a closure and a method without an object/reference: you *might* be looking for a "local method"... but local methods aren't anonymous :) so: can you please be very specific about what features it is that are important to you? there are lots of options here, and it isn't clear what you're after, so it is very hard to offer guidance

Comment: Dmitry has answered my question, actually. This discussion is now just frosting. I would like to know what would make it truly a closure; But that can be a different SO post.

Comment: @MattW strictly speaking (just to clarify some unclear wording I used): neither of them has a closure - I tripped over there. A lexical closure would occur when some value *outside* the anonymous method (or local method) is used *inside* - which requires the construction of a capture-context to hoist the variable into a context that can be used by either. In the case of anonymous method, the capture context is an object; in the case of a local method, it is a struct (because the lifetime is more predictable)

Comment: @MattW so: it is the first version that *has* the closure (because it uses `str` inside the anonymous method); the second version **does not** have a closure